# UML: how to define an unique occurence of a type in a group

Tags: uml, unique, one-to-many, entity-relationship

Lets say you have the objects CounterGroup and Counter with 1:n relation.
Counter has the attribut "type". 
I can easily show in UML (Entity-Relation-Diagram) that CounterGroup can have many Counter.
But how do i show that only a unique occurence of Counter->type per CounterGroup is allowed?

Answer (score 3):

You will simply attach a constraint like this:

[image]